# Why are Stein manifolds/spaces the analog of affine varieties/schemes in algebraic geometry?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, complex-geometry

I presume this is a GAGA-style result, but I cannot find a reference.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Also like affine varieties, we have:

> Theorem. A complex manifold is Stein if and only if it embeds into some $\mathbb{C}^N$ as a closed complex submanifold.

For the "only if" direction, see Hörmander, *An Introduction to Complex Analysis in Several variables*, Theorem 5.3.9. For the converse, an argument is contained on pp 109-110  of Hörmander, immediately after the definition of Stein manifold.

Comment: In particular, the analytification of a complex algebraic variety is a Stein space.

Comment: @Earthliŋ: You probably mean affine algebraic variety.

Comment: @JérômePoineau Yes, of course. Somehow "affine" got lost when I added "complex"...

Answer (score 18):

I believe the reason for this is Cartan's 'Theorem B': for a Stein manifold $\mathrm{X}$ sheaf cohomology vanishes, $\mathrm{H}^n(\mathrm{X},-)=0$ for $n\geqslant 1$, and this property characterises Stein manifolds among complex manifolds. In the same way affine schemes are characterised among (nice) schemes by cohomology vanishing (this is a theorem of Serre). This comes up in the proof of the cohomological comparison result which is part of GAGA, see for example SGA 1, Exposé XII.

Comment: There is no way to be completely   tactful here; the vanishing condition is for *coherent analytic coefficients* only. It is certainly not true for all coefficients, e.g. $X= \mathbb{C}^*$ and cohomology with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$ is not zero, but $X$ is Stein.

Comment: @DonuArapura this was understood... on the scheme side you are also not going to consider sheaves which are not even $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules or which have no finiteness properties.

Comment: OK, but I'll leave the comment, since not everyone would understand the hidden assumptions.